# How set cookies in response in SSP Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to set cookies to response in SSP application (Netsuite application ) I have add code like below

```
response.setHeader("Set-Cookies", "tc=tc;path=/");
            nlapiSetRedirectURL('EXTERNAL', session.getSiteSettings(['touchpoints']).touchpoints.login);
```

But it is not working and giving error like

Error 400: SSS_INVALID_HEADER
One or more headers are not valid.

Could any body know how to set cookies in Netsuite SSP application

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason why you are trying to use HTTP headers to set cookies in your SSP application?

You can use [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/document.cookie) instead:

```
<script>
    document.cookie = 'tc=tc;path=/
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

If you are using a custom domain for checkout it should works. if not, you can't set a cookie between different domains but you can try passing the cookie as a parameter:

`nlapiSetRedirectURL('EXTERNAL',session.getSiteSettings(['touchpoints']).touchpoints.login + '?tc=VALUE');`

then read your parameters in checkout.ssp:

`var tcCookieValue = request.getParameter('tc')`

and use `document.cookie` to create the cookie

Comment: Yes , because there is a redirect in header, java script won't execute

Comment: If you are using a custom domain for checkout it should works. if not, you can't set a cookie between different domains but you can try passing the cookie as a parameter ` nlapiSetRedirectURL('EXTERNAL', session.getSiteSettings(['touchpoints']).touchpoints.login + '?tc=VALUE');` and then read your parameters in checkout.ssp `request.getParameter('tc')` and  use `document.cookie` to set the cookie

Comment: Actually we are using some some custom session cookies to store few values, and we want to clear out those cookies when there is logout (in case user is not closing the browser) As clearing cookies may not work some time, we are planing store some wrong  value. Alternate way is set cookies using java script and do the redirct using java script.